# SQL Server user running SSIS package getting EXECUTE permissions error when they have that permission

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017

We have a user running an SSIS package from Visual Studio.

The step that is failing is it is trying to run a stored proc but the error within Visual Studio is "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xxx', database 'yyy'....

But this user has EXECUTE permissions on the database in general, they are accessing SQL Server using integrated security / Windows login.

Comment: Difficult to say why it is happening. Try to look at the connection string the ssis is using for the sql activity.

Answer (score 0):

When I granted EXECUTE permission on the stored proc specifically, it works from SSIS.

The user been a member of db_executor database role (without specific object permissions) doesn't seem to be enough for SSIS.

Comment: There is no built-in [database role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16#fixed-database-roles) called *db_executor*.

Comment: Sounds like some developer on your end created a new (user defined) role called `db_executor` and forgot to add this procedure to it.